# Handling Recursive Nested Object Lists in C# for CSV Output

Tags: c#, nested-lists

I'm grappling with a C# object structure intended for CSV export. This structure has multi-layered nested lists, some potentially empty, and they can be recursive. While I'm presenting a simplified model below, the actual structure I'm dealing with is significantly more intricate.

Here's an illustrative representation:

```
class A
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public List<B> BItems { get; set; }
    public List<C> CItems { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public D RelationshipType { get; set; }
    public List<B> SubBItems { get; set; } // Recursive list
}

class C
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
}

class D
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Consider this sample data:

```
AItems = [{    Prop1: "Code1",    Prop2: "Title1",    BItems: [        {            Name: "Name1",             ID: "ID1",             RelationshipType: {Label: "Label1", Value: "Value1"},            SubBItems: [                {Name: "SubName1", ID: "SubID1", RelationshipType: {Label: "SubLabel1", Value: "SubValue1"}}            ]
        },
        {Name: "Name2", ID: "ID2", RelationshipType: {Label: "Label2", Value: "Value2"}}
    ],
    CItems: [{Year: "Year1"}]
}, {
    Prop1: "Code2",
    Prop2: "Title2",
    BItems: [{Name: "Name1", ID: "ID1", RelationshipType: {Label: "Label1", Value: "Value1"}}],
    CItems: [{Year: "Year1"}, {Year: "Year2"}]
}];
```

The intended CSV output would be:

```
Prop1, Prop2, B_Name, B_ID, D_Label, D_Value, B_SubB_Name, B_SubB_ID, D_SubB_Label, D_SubB_Value, C_Year
Code1, Title1, Name1, ID1, Label1, Value1, SubName1, SubID1, SubLabel1, SubValue1, Year1
Code1, Title1, Name2, ID2, Label2, Value2, , , , , Year1
Code2, Title2, Name1, ID1, Label1, Value1, , , , , Year1
Code2, Title2, Name1, ID1, Label1, Value1, , , , , Year2
```

I'm attempting to generate the rows, but my approach is struggling to aptly merge objects from parallel lists, notably lists at the same depth.

```
public static void GenerateRows(
            List<Dictionary<string, string>> records,
            Dictionary<string, string> currentRow,
            object obj,
            string prefix,
            HashSet<string> allHeaders)
        {
            if (obj == null) return;

            var type = obj.GetType();

            if (obj is IEnumerable && type != typeof(string))
            {
                foreach (var item in obj as IEnumerable)
                {
                    var clonedRow = new Dictionary<string, string>(currentRow);
                    GenerateRows(records, clonedRow, item, prefix, allHeaders);
                }
                return;
            }

            // Process properties for the current object
            ProcessProperties(records, currentRow, obj, prefix, allHeaders);
        }

        private static void ProcessProperties(
            List<Dictionary<string, string>> records,
            Dictionary<string, string> row,
            object obj,
            string prefix,
            HashSet<string> allHeaders)
        {
            var type = obj.GetType();

            // Create a list to temporarily hold generated rows from lists.
            List<Dictionary<string, string>> tempListRows = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

            foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
            {
                if (prop.CanRead && prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                {
                    var val = prop.GetValue(obj);
                    var propName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) ? prop.Name : $"{prefix}_{prop.Name}";

                    if (val is string || val is ValueType)
                    {
                        row[propName] = val?.ToString();
                        allHeaders.Add(propName);
                    }
                    else if (val is IEnumerable && prop.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                    {
                        List<Dictionary<string, string>> newRows = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
                        foreach (var item in val as IEnumerable)
                        {
                            var newRow = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                            GenerateRows(newRows, newRow, item, propName, allHeaders);
                        }
                        tempListRows.AddRange(newRows);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GenerateRows(records, row, val, propName, allHeaders);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Merge rows
            if (tempListRows.Count == 0)
            {
                records.Add(row);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var tempRow in tempListRows)
                {
                    var mergedRow = new Dictionary<string, string>(row);
                    foreach (var kvp in tempRow)
                    {
                        mergedRow[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
                    }
                    records.Add(mergedRow);
                }
            }
        }
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _" a C# object structure **intended for CSV export**. This structure has multi-layered nested lists, some potentially empty, and they can be recursive."_  (emphasis by me) That's contradictory. If it is _intended_ for CSV, it would have been a flat structure to begin with.

Comment: The original input is JSON, and I do not need everything in the JSON, so I have converted it to c# object. Now, I need to export it to CSV. That is why it is not a flat structure at the start.

Comment: Even without the self-reference that would be messy ( **very** messy ) but doable. It's basically a cross-join. But the self-reference needs cycle-detection ...

Comment: D could be completely denormalized into B, ...

Comment: ... are you _sure_ you 100% _must have_ CSV? This is not going to be fun.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understand that the solution would create lot's of duplicated data that is something that should not be done. But I need the output to be in the form of csv.

Comment: I don't care about the duplication. It is what it is. Just the self-reference in B explodes this. Even if you manage to successfully implement the cycle-detection, the nesting is not (really) bounded, so this can blow up in your face _really quickly_.

Comment: Yes it must 100% be exported to csv. I have actully tried to mention your concern before but they refuce to change the spects. I'm really glad to find someone that understand what I am talking about.

Comment: It might be worth it to somewhat push back. Even if it is just a soft requirement (agreement on paper => specification): if you can get "them" to let's say 5 Levels of Nesting max, you would at least know your worst case ... as is, your worst case (even if it never happens in real-life) must be assumed to be "infinity".

Comment: Actually, they did mention that at the moment it's only 5 layers but has the possibility of increasing to maybe 6. But the total number of layers even used in real live cases should not be more than 10.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a problem with a language but wants a "how-to" to solve a problem which the user could solve on their own.

Comment: Then 10 is your number :D Not that 10 Layers won't make for a humongous file, but it's significantly less than infinity.